# How to prove that a custom iterative algorithm will determine all shortest paths to a graph node?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I'm not sure what the following algorithm does but it seems that it calculates the shortest paths from a node $t$.

Initially we're given a graph $G=(V,E)$ with non-negative weights $c(e) \ge0$ for each edge $e\in E$ and we're given a node $t\in V$.

The algorithm is as follows:

> Initialize array $A$ such that $A[v] = 0$ if $v=t$ else $A[v]=\infty$.
>
> Outer loop which is repeated continually
>
> $\quad$ Inner loop: we scan all edges in lexicographical order and for every $e=(u,v)\in E$ we $\quad$ do the following:
>
> $\qquad$ if $A[v] >A[u]+c(e)$ then $A[v] =A[u]+c(e)$
>
> $\quad$ if no updates were performed in the inner loop the algorithm exits.

I need to prove by induction what the algorithm does. For example for the following graph below and if $s=b$ the initialization of $A$ will be as follows:

[image]

Then the first run of the inner loop would be:

1) $A[1]$ is not bigger than $A[0]$ so we do nothing

2) $A[2]$ is bigger than $A[1]$ so $A[2]=2$

3) $A[3]$ is bigger than $A[2]$ so $A[3]=5$

The next time the inner loop will not make any updates because all the reachable nodes were already updated.

I'm not really sure if I understood correctly what the algorithm does and how to prove this inductively.

How does the fact that the algorithm checks nodes in lexicographical order come into play?

Comment: The ordering of the edges doesn't really matter, it is only there to specify some order relative to which you will iterate them. The algorithm remains correct for every ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove by induction that for every iteration $i$, the array $A$ during this iteration, $A_i$, contains the weights of some paths originating at $t$. More formally, for all $v\in V$, $A_i[v]$ is either $\infty$ or the weight of some path from $t$ to $v$.

Now, it is easy to show that the values of $A_i$ are monotonically non increasing, which combined with the above statement implies that the algorithm terminates. I leave the details to you.

Comment: Why is the order decreasing because all the cells of the array before $t$ have $\infty$ values and afterwards they have some integer values?

Comment: No, according to what you're saying the integer values may yet grow. Monotonicity here means that for $i<j$ and every $v\in V$ : $A_i[v] \ge A_j[v]$.

Comment: But how do we know that the values are monotonically decreasing?

Comment: Examine your algorithm carefully, when and how is $A$ being updated? I think you have enough details to write the complete proof on your own.

Comment: In my example the array $A$ finally is: $\infty,0,0+2,2+3=\infty,0,2,5$ according to the explanation I gave in the OP. If it's correct then the values are increasing

Comment: How does this show that the values are increasing? The values were updated from $\infty$ to $2,5$. I encourage you to think on this alone for a while, at this point I will not comment any further.

Comment: Did you mean that a given node $A[i]$ will either remain to be $\infty$ or receive some value, and of course any number is less than infinity. It that context each $A[i]$ value is decreasing. I thought you meant that the whole sequence of the array values is decreasing.